# How to design a simple and efficient MySQL blacklist table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose I have user table `my_users` in which there is a primary key `id`. Also, I wish to design (in MySQL) a simple blacklist table, whose declaration looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS black_list (
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  bad_string VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES my_users(id),
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id, bad_string));
```

The interpretation of any row in the `black_list` is that a user with the ID `user_id` wants to blacklist the string `bad_string`. Obviously, `user_id` cannot be unique since a single user may have more than one blacklisted string. Other way around, `bad_string` cannot be unique since more than one users may have blacklisted the same string. However, the pair (`user_id`, `bad_string`) should be unique since it makes no sense for the user to black list the same string more than once.

When we select a black list via a user ID (`SELECT * FROM black_list WHERE user_id = X`) in the worst case, MySQL will have to scan the entire `black_list` table.

My question here is: is there a way for running the above `SELECT` statement in sublinear time with regard to the number of rows in the `black_list` table? If yes, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: The query would utilize the clustered index right? Maybe I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: I don't understand "running in a sublinear time"

Comment: What about a simple relational setup?  One table that has **users info** -- One table that has **blacklist info** and a "pivot" table connecting the two?

Comment: @Zak Possibly. The only difference in my real setup is that `bad_string` is actually an `ENUM`.

Comment: @FrankerZ "Linear time" would occur whenever DBMS has to scan through all the rows of a table.

Comment: @coderodde Why would you use an ENUM for this?

Comment: @Uueerdo The set of all possible `bad_strings` is really small (around 15) and those enumerations are to be used in the other parts of a system I am currently working on.

Comment: @coderodde Seems odd to me, but I am obviously not familiar with the specifics involved. Just need to make the obligatory message that enums can behave weird in comparisons, and adding a new value to them requires an ALTER TABLE (that requires the entire table be rebuilt) that could be costly if a high user count makes that table rather large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that `SELECT * FROM black_list WHERE user_id = X` will have to scan the entire black_list table is incorrect.

In this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a8cf9/2), you can see it's using an index:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type |   table    | type | possible_keys |   key   | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered |    Extra    |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | black_list | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY |       4 | const |    1 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the meaning of information in the table of your answer. Should I simply use the two SQL statements in my question as is and stop worrying about performance?

Comment: If you click on the fiddle you can see the plan data (which is the table posted above). This is the "equivalent" of using `EXPLAIN` or `Include Actual Execution Plan` in SQL Server. @FrankerZ is demonstrating that the (clustered) index is used for this query. The point being to allay your concern about a table scan. Since user_id is the first column in the clustered index, the table itself will be sorted by user_id. Thus, when you query `WHERE user_id =`, the clustered index will be used and the entire table (usually) won't be scanned. The engine will seek to the user_id in the query.

Comment: Perhaps the disconnect here is that by adding a `PRIMARY KEY` to your table, the engine automatically creates a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on those columns. Note the difference when you click "View Execution Plan" here when I have not included a PRIMARY KEY http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4905/1

Comment: @JacobH OK, I think I am beginning to see the more detailed picture here. My question mostly stems from the fact that while I "see" how a DBMS may create and use single-column indices, the indices over more than one column puzzle me.

Comment: The PRIMARY KEY defines the CLUSTERED INDEX, which is the only index that modifies the underlying structure of the table and the data is ordered by those columns. Consider these fiddles, one with a primary key: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e8f6c2/2 and one with none: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7adc08/1 Note the ordering of the values returned by bad_string in the second fiddle match the order they were inserted, while the first (with PRIMARY KEY) is returned in the order defined by the index (alphabetical first by user_id, second by bad_string).

Comment: Final note: Ordering is not guaranteed for a few reasons, this was a simple example to show how the indexes work. If you need a specific order to your data you should *always* use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT` or with `TOP`.